# What is the best way to test this? Binary digits with 4 positions

Tags: java, binary, combinatorics

Consider 4 input fields A, B, C and D on a web surface. The user can fill any of these arbitrary. There are 16 combinations of how to fill these fields. The ones allowed are:

```
A B C D
-------
1 0 0 0
1 1 0 0
1 1 1 0
1 1 1 1
```

where 1 means `not null` and 0 means `null`.

I am using the MVC pattern with jsf. I don't want the logic to be in the view, but rather in the controller. What is the best way to check this in Java?

I implemented two solutions so far:

#### Solution 1:

```
@Override
public boolean isInputInvalid(Integer a, Integer b, Integer c, Integer d) {
    if (isNotSet(a) && isNotSet(b) && isNotSet(c) && isNotSet(d) {
        return true;
    }
    return (firstParameterDoesNotExistAndSecondDoesExist(a, b)) || (firstParameterDoesNotExistAndSecondDoesExist(b, c)) || (firstParameterDoesNotExistAndSecondDoesExist(c, d));
}

private boolean firstParameterDoesNotExistAndSecondDoesExist(Integer firstParameter, Integer secondParameter) {
    return isNotSet(firstParameter) && !isNotSet(secondParameter);
}

private boolean isNotSet(Integer parameter) {
    return parameter == null;
}
```

#### Solution 2:

```
public boolean isInputValid(Integer a, Integer b, Integer c, Integer d) {
    if (exists(a) && !exists(b) && !exists(c) && !exists(d) || //
            exists(a) && exists(b) && !exists(c) && !exists(d) || //
            exists(a) && exists(b) && exists(c) && !exists(d) || //
            exists(a) && exists(b) && exists(c) && exists(d)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean exists(Integer level) {
    return level != null;
}
```

#### Note:

The first methods checks if input is **invalid**, while the second checks if input is  **valid** (note the names of the methods).

I wrote 16 unit test cases, which all run green with both versions.

Do you have any hints/tips/tricks on how to get the code even more readable?

Comment: You should had to your post that a logical `1` equals a `not null` object and a loigcal `0` equals a `null`object

Comment: What do you mean by 'best'? Best-readable? Fastest? Easiest extendable?

Comment: It has not to be extendable. I want it do be readable and in 'clean-code-manner'.

Comment: Looks like this question should be posted on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Valid combinations are: 1000, 1100, 1110 and 1111

If you only care about readability:

```
public static List<String> validOptions = Arrays.asList("1000","1100","1110","1111");

public boolean isValid(Integer a, Integer b, Integer c, Integer d)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(a==null ? 0 : 1); 
    sb.append(b==null ? 0 : 1), 
    sb.append(c==null ? 0 : 1); 
    sb.append(d==null ? 0 : 1);
    return validOptions.contains(sb.toString());
}
```

Note that this is not the fastest or cleanest solution (wastes some CPU and memory)

Comment: Note that I have Integers which can be null!

Comment: I did some changes to your example: I defined 6 constants: LEVEL_GIVEN = "1000", LEVEL_JOB_GIVEN = "1100", ..., GIVEN = 1, NOT_GIVEN = 0; and a method isGiven(Integer input) {return input == null}; This makes it more readable. To be honest, I am not sure if my Solution 1 is not even more readable!?

Comment: @Chris311 That is a matter of taste as well :). I think my solution provides three things: 1. quick visual check of valid options,  2. simple visual logic that converts the `Integer` to either `0` or `1` and 3. a simple 'check' if the constructed String is indeed valid.

Comment: I edited my initial post, you can now read it quite fluently.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this for an arbitrary number of parameters, pass in `true` or `false` (if not null / null) in this:

```
static boolean isValid(boolean... params) {
    boolean set = true;
    for (boolean param : params) {
        if (!set && param) return false;
        set = param;
    }
    return params[0];
}
```

Or much cooler (and IMHO readable), but less performant, use regex on the array's `toString()`:

```
static boolean isValid(boolean... params) {
    return Arrays.toString(params).matches("\\[true(, true)*(, false)*]");
}
```

which ever implementation you use, you would call it like:

```
if (isValid(a != null, b != null, c != null, d != null))
```

Comment: This does not work for true false false false which returns false but is valid.

Comment: Oh, I did not see your edit. This is really awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Not fancy but fast and simple:

```
static boolean isValid(boolean a, boolean b, boolean c, boolean d) {
    return a && (b || !c) && (c || !d);
}
```

Call:

```
isValid(a != null, b != null, c != null, d != null);
```

Comment: Nice solution, but in my mind one can not understand this as fast as the solution from RobAu e.g.

Comment: @Chris311 I agree, but still I thought that this solution shouldn't be missing here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand why you need this. Rather than a method that tests if input is valid, it would be much better to only allow valid input in the first place.

```
// This method is private, so you can't call it with arbitrary arguments.
private void privateMethod(Integer a, Integer b, Integer c, Integer d) {
    // do something();
}

public void method(int a) {
    privateMethod(a, null, null, null);
}

public void method(int a, int b) {
    privateMethod(a, b, null, null);
}

public void method(int a, int b, int c) {
    privateMethod(a, b, c, null);
}

public void method(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    privateMethod(a, b, c, d);
}
```

The way to modify this to any number of arguments (not just 4) is to have a method with signature

```
public void method(int... a)
```

Then, if the length of the array passed is less than the required length, you can just use `null` for the remaining inputs.

If this does not address your problem, I think you should consider editing your question to give an example of your use case, because I suspect there is a better way to achieve what you require.

Comment: I can't do this because a, b, c and d represent input fields on a web surface. I don't want to do input checks in the jsf page, so I need to do it in the code. I will edit my initial post, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a pattern with a two dimensional array.
The advantage is that it is easy to adjust, and add additional information to it.
Here is a tiny example with your conditions.
In the end all you have to read is the pattern that is initialized in the static block, which is quite easy to read.

```
// Every boolean array in a dimension represents a valid pattern 
private static boolean[][] pattern;

static {
    pattern = new boolean[4][4];
    pattern[0] = new boolean[]{true, false, false, false};
    pattern[1] = new boolean[]{true, true,  false, false};
    pattern[2] = new boolean[]{true, true,  true,  false};
    pattern[3] = new boolean[]{true, true,  true,  true};
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Testing an invalid combination
    System.out.println(test(new Integer[]{1,null,3,null}));
    // Testing a valid combination
    System.out.println(test(new Integer[]{1,2,3,null}));
}

private static boolean test(Integer[] input) {
    // cast the input to a boolean array that can be compared to the pattern.
    boolean[] arr = createArr(input);
    for(int i = 0;i<pattern.length;++i) {
        if(Arrays.equals(pattern[i], arr)) { // Check if the pattern exists in the list of valid pattern. If it exists, then this is a valid combination
            return true;
        }
    }
    // the loop never found a valid combination, hence it returns false.
    return false;
}

// This is just a helping method to create a boolean array out of an int array. It casts null to true and !null to false.
private static boolean[] createArr(Integer[] input) {
    boolean[] output = new boolean[input.length];
    for(int i = 0;i<input.length; ++i) {
        output[i] = input[i] != null;
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: I thought of a solution similar to this as well. But in my mind it takes more time to understand this than the above from my post.

Comment: @Chris311 the *improvement* with this approach is that this is easier to modify if later your problem needs to support 5 or more variables. Still, this can be improved.

Comment: @Chris311 It took me some times to understand your tests. I personally find the array solution easier to understand

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza yeah it totally can be improved, it´s just a fast and tiny example.

Comment: The 4 variables will remain stable; but yes I see the benefit of adaption here. I will think about your solution. Your solution does not seem much like 'Clean Code' to me...

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution. Involves more code but for me it's easier to understand:

```
boolean isInputInvalid(Object ... args) {
    int notNullDataIndex = -1;
    for (int i = args.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (args[i] != null) {
            notNullDataIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (notNullDataIndex < 0) return false;
    for (int i = notNullDataIndex; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (args[i] == null) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```